# Как правильно пишется "вниз" и "по центру"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

В низ, или вниз?

"Чтобы поставить точку вниз и по центру нажмите..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее слитно. Но без контекста не очень понятно, что там именно надо сформулировать, отсюда сомнения..

Если "где?", то правильно - ***внизу***. Если "куда?", то ***"вниз"***. 
А *"в низ"* - это только в сочетании "в низ чего?" - типа  "в низ ящика" и т. п. Малоупотребительно в современном языке. И уж точно не в сочетании с "по центру"